# tabular: cellcolor fills only part of cell if makecell is used

Tags: tables, color, makecell

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c }
\cellcolor{blue!=10} \makecell{ 1 \\ 2}  \\
\cellcolor{blue!=10} 10000  \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

The above cell is only filled partially in horizontal direction. I want the same area to be filled in both cells, i.e. that the left and right border of the colored rectangle coincide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead you can try the `nicematrix` package.

The `\Block[<options>]{}{<cell content>}` command is a 1 row x 1 column block and allows you to use `\\` in the cell content.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{nicematrix}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \cellcolor{blue!=10} \makecell{1 \\ 2}  \\
        \cellcolor{blue!=10} 10000   \\
    \end{tabular}
    
    \bigskip
    
     Using  \verb|\usepackage{nicematrix}|\bigskip
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c}
        \Block[fill=blue!10]{}{1 \\ 2}  \\
        \cellcolor{blue!=10} 10000   \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

May I ask, why not do it this way (why do you need `makecell`?):

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\cellcolor{blue!=10} 1 \\ 
\cellcolor{blue!=10} 2 \\
\cellcolor{blue!=10} 10000 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano ;)

Comment: You're very welcome.